# How do I find the associate matrix of $f(A) = A \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to find the associate matrix of this linear function ($A$ is a 2x2 matrix)

$f:M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$

$f(A) = A \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & \lambda 
 \end{bmatrix}$

$A  \epsilon M_{2 \times 2} ,  \lambda  \epsilon  \mathbb{R}$

I have tried to find the matrix M such that

$MA = A\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & \lambda 
 \end{bmatrix}$

But I really don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just to clarify, where does $A$ lie?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, you just get $M=A\pmatrix{1&2\cr3&\lambda\cr}A^{-1}$, right?

Comment: Are you trying to find the matrix of the linear map $f:M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$? If so you need to pick a basis of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ and see what $f$ does to each element. You'll then get the $4\times 4$ matrix for $f$. It won't act on $A$ by matrix multiplication, it's the wrong size.

Comment: To find a matrix representation of the linear map $f$, you need to **fix a basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$**. Then you will be able to see how $f$ acts on each basis vector in $\mathfrak{B}$. This will give rise to a $4\times4$ matrix $M$ describing how each *coordinate vector* $[A]_{\mathfrak{B}}$ of $A \in M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ is transformed to another coordinate vector: $$[f(A)]_{\mathfrak{B}}=M[A]_{\mathfrak{B}}.$$

Comment: Also, I am skeptical about the idea that $f$ reduces to a usual matrix multiplication from the left in $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$. (For this to happen, we must have that $A\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&\lambda\end{pmatrix}A^{-1}$ is a constant function of $A$ as pointed out in Gerry's comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, suppose we have a linear map $f:V\to V$, and an (ordered) basis ${\frak B}=v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n$ of $V$. Then the matrix of $f$ with respect to ${\frak B}$ is the $n\times n$ array $(f_{ij})$ where the entries are given by the equations
$$
f(v_i)=\sum_{j=0}^n  f_{ji}v_j.
$$

In this case $V$ is the $4$ dimensional space of $2\times 2$ matrices, and we can take the usual basis $v_1:=e_{11},v_2:=e_{12},v_3:=e_{21},v_4:=e_{22}$ of the space of matrices.
[Here $e_{ij}$ is the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$ place and $0$ elsewhere.

We now have to calculate each $f(v_i)$ and express it as a linear combination of the $v_i$. I will only do $v_2$ and leave you to do the other three in the same way.

We have

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(v_2) &=&
f(e_{12})\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\ 3 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{pmatrix}3 & \lambda\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\\
&=&3e_{11}+\lambda e_{12}+0e_{21}+0e_{22}\\
&=&3v_1+\lambda v_2+0v_3+0v_4.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
But by the definition of the matrix of $f$ we should have
$$
f(v_2)= f_{12} v_1 +f_{22} v_2 +f_{32} v_3 +f_{42} v_4
$$
so the second column of the matrix of $f$ is $(3,\lambda,0,0)^T$, or if you prefer we have so far got that the matrix of $f$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
? & 3 &? & ?\\
? & \lambda &? & ?\\
? & 0 &? & ?\\
? & 0 &? & ?\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I think that you should be able to calculate the other three columns yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I did not understand it fully. Can you explain why the associated matrix is a 4x4 and how to obtain it given the basis that we found by computing the function for the canonical basis matrices?

Comment: Alas. Do you know the definition of the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to chosen bases? [as per Sanchul Lee's comments.]

Comment: No, I am new to linear algebra, what do I need to understand this exercise?

Comment: I have much expanded my answer.